# PowerApp - flow, application and Excel file

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I need your help with a simple project for work, but for which I am stuck. The whole environment is under O365: the objective is to retrieve requests through a form, and then to be able to consult these requests with a web interface.

So I created a form, with a PowerApp flow that triggers on each validation, and inserts the results into an Excel file (in a table, it adds a new line), hosted on OneDrive.

I then created a PowerApp application to list each entry in the table. Clicking on the menu on the left displays the line details in the menu on the right :

[image: Screenshot]

At this stage, I have several problems:

1. I'd like to add a "Validate" button to validate the request. Adding the button is straightforward, but I can't seem to trigger an action when it's clicked - ideally, I'd like to delete the line in the Excel file, and copy the information to another Excel file.
2. there are also 2 handy default buttons (circled in red on the image), allowing you to modify fields. I have 3 columns in my Excel file, which are empty by default, and I'd like to be able to complete them via drop-down lists through this web interface.  I can create a drop-down list, but I can't link it to my Excel file - when I modify the fields, these 3 columns are not modified in the Excel file.
3. Ideally, the "Validate" button should be disabled when field modification is activated.

Many thanks for your help!